# c# overlay with grayscale image as opacity mask

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, overlay

I have 2 image files `background.jpg`, `mask.jpg` - one of which is grayscale image.

I want to read these 2 image files as input and write overlayed image output to `output.jpg`.

The grayscale image should be opacity mask.

I googled about image process of wpf, but they all shows xaml examples.

I want to do this process with c# code. Any advice, please.

**Updated:**

I wrote the code by using OpenCV and it's working good.

```
public static void QcOverlay(string background_file, string mask_file, string output_file)
{
    // Read mask_file with alpha channel
    Mat overlay = Cv2.ImRead(mask_file, ImreadModes.Unchanged);
    Mat src = Cv2.ImRead(background_file);

    // Extract alpha from mask_file and generate mask from overlay image
    Mat mask = new Mat();
    Mat[] rgba = Cv2.Split(overlay);    
    Cv2.Threshold(rgba[3], mask, 245, 255, ThresholdTypes.Binary);
    Cv2.CvtColor(mask, mask, ColorConversionCodes.GRAY2BGR);

    // Convert overlay image to BGR for bitwise arithmetic
    Cv2.CvtColor(overlay,overlay, ColorConversionCodes.BGRA2BGR);
    
    Mat dst = new Mat();

    // Image overlay
    Cv2.BitwiseOr(src,mask, dst);   
    Cv2.BitwiseAnd(dst,overlay, dst);

    // Output
    Cv2.ImWrite(output_file, dst);
}
```

*I tried to use EmguCV instead of OpenCV, but failed to install EmguCV library on my project. EmguCV implementation could be more simple, I think.*

Comment: the equation for (per-pixel) alpha-blending is `pixel_new = overlay * alpha + pixel_old * (1-alpha)`, add some scaling (alpha being 0 to 1, or 0 to 255?), apply to all pixels, and you're done. give it a try. please review [ask] and [mre]. show your effort.

Comment: (1) draw on bitmap ([get it as an array, change the pixel values](https://csharpexamples.com/tag/fast-bitmap-access/)) (2) show bitmap on GUI https://swharden.com/csdv/system.drawing/quickstart-wpf/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: During coding, I can't understand what differences between Image, Bitmap, BitmapSource, BitmapImage is.

Comment: emgu is dead. use "opencvsharp"